# Local TFJS Model (Transfer Learning MobileNet) returns wrong predictions

Tags: tensorflow, expo, tensorflow.js

I use transfer learning with MobileNet to solve an image problem. I loaded the images with ImageDataGenerator `(rescale=1./127.5)`.

After training I converted it with:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --weight_shard_size_bytes 10000000000 model tmp
```

The next step is to load my model and my weight file in my Expo App:

```
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson,modelWeight));
```

And normalize my input image:

```
const normalized  = imageTensor.toFloat().sub(127.5).div(127.5);
```

The output is completely wrong (One class always 1 and all other ~0)

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Comment: Try to rescale with `1./127.5 - 1`. MobileNet wants images in a range of (-1,1).

Comment: @Frightera Like this:  imageTensor.toFloat().div(127.5).sub(1); ? Didn't work but th :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this normalization:

```
const normalized  = imageTensor.toFloat().sub(127).div(128);
```